# ActionCable on AWS with ElastiCache: Error Received data without a live WebSocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache, actioncable

When I use ElastiCashe service as redis server for ActionCcable , I have error with websocket:

```
 Received data without a live WebSocket
```

And a new ws connection is closed (499 status from nginx).

When I install and run redis server locally on EB instance, ActionCable work fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Just running into this same issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491453/actioncable-with-elastic-beanstalk-and-classic-load-balancer-499-nginx-code